# revers keyframe animation on hover out

Tags: html, css, css-animations

```css
.btn-text {
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  color: red;
  padding: 8px 12px 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
  display:block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  animation: before 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.btn-text::before, .btn-text::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.btn-text:active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn-text:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.btn-text::before, .btn-text::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.btn-text::before {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}
.btn-text::after {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
}
.btn-text:hover::before, .btn-text:hover::after {
  animation: border 0.5s ease forwards;
}
.btn-text span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 8px;
}


@keyframes border {
   to{
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#!" class="btn-text " style="width: fit-content">know
                more
                <span></span>
            </a>
```

I am trying to add a cool hover in animation effect. When I hover over the button I am calling an animation which scaling up borders .

My problem is that when I hover out of button it goes back to the initial state without animation.

I want that the same animation should reverse when I hover out.

Comment: use transition instead

Comment: how ? I seen some answers but didn't figured out

Comment: instead of calling the animaton you simply call `transform: scale3d(1,1,1);` and then read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: well this animation is made up of two elements , that what make me confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an *animation* for this, you need a transition...like so:

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyPgPBj)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-text {
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  color: red;
  padding: 8px 12px 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.btn-text::before,
.btn-text::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.btn-text:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.btn-text::before,
.btn-text::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.btn-text::before {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}

.btn-text::after {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
}

.btn-text:hover::before {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.btn-text:hover::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.btn-text span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#!" class="btn-text " style="width: fit-content">know more
   <span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked as expected , but can you please explain me ?